# Video player for own website (with youtube)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add video's on my site. Some from youtube, some not.

following w3 schools this is the best solution

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240" />
  </object> 
</video>
```

1. My question was what should I do if I only have 1 youtube link.
2. My other question is if I have recorded something and I put that on my pc or I download somewhere a .flv/mp4 file.. do I need to convert it to ogg / webm / mp4

I have now only used the mp4 line because I have an mp4 file. but in firefox it won't play and in IE it won't show.

this is the site : http://jdkmedia.nl/Atlanta/media.php with a downloaded youtube movie in mp4 format.

(P.S I am using windows 8 , IE 10 , chrome 21, firefox 14)

Thanks in advance and edit if you see things that should be edited.

**Question answered/closed , feel free to post more anwers**

Comment: Never ever *ever* consider anything from W3Schools as the "best" solution. They're wrong half the time. [See w3fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Wow that's new for me. thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to embed youtube video's this is the correct method

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo"
frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Enormous thanks :D
I will use youtube as upload and than use that html.
You saved my day. (I had found some code that looks like this but that won't work) now it finially works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success using ffmpeg to convert video files to html5 compatible formats.  Getting the command line correct can be a little fiddly, but there are sites that can help if you google (e.g. http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/)

In your case, you would probably use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 \
       -b 345k -s 640x360 output.ogg
```

Comment: Thank you , but is it always needed to convert the video files if you want them to play them cross browser without problems?